# JPA OneToMany Relationship with JoinTable - unable to delete element

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have some JPA relation issues.

I have this OneToMany relation with a joinTable in my entity called "Requete" :

```
@OrderBy("index")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "requete_select_colonne", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "requete_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "select_colonne_id"))
private SortedSet<SelectColonne> selectColonnes = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(SelectColonne::getIndex));
```

When i'm trying to delete one of the element of selectColonnes I get this error :

```
requete.getSelectColonnes().remove(selectColonne);
this.requeteRepository.save(requete);

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: UPDATE ou DELETE sur la table « select_colonne » viole la contrainte de clé étrangère
« fk_requete_select_colonne_colonne » de la table « requete_select_colonne »
Détail : La clé (id)=(552) est toujours référencée à partir de la table « requete_select_colonne ».
```

I think it's trying to delete the entry in table select_colonne before the one in the join table requete_select_colonne.

Any recommandation ? I would like to keep the joinTable if possible.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the element doesn't know about the owner, then you must remove from the owner collection first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @neil, that's what I'm doing :
    `requete.getSelectColonnes().remove(selectColonne);`
    `this.requeteRepository.save(requete);`

Comment: so do a flush after the remove from the collection to force your JPA provider to do that first

Comment: This isn't working even if I flush. I have just noticed that removing the first element of the SortedSet works. I don't understand why...